# Equivalence of DFA' definitions

Tags: automata, finite-automata, simulation

According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automaton) DFA accepts word $w$ by one of two definitions:

1. A word $w$ is accepted by $M$ if $\hat\delta(q_0,w)\in F$.
2. A word $w=w_1w_2\dots w_n$ is accepted by $M$ if $\exists r_0,\dots,r_n\in Q$ such that:

   - $r_0=q_0$
   - $\delta(r_i,w_{i+1})=r_{i+1} \ \forall 0\le i<n$
   - $r_n\in F$

Assuming that some word $w$ is accepted by definition 1, how can we show it is accepted by definition 2?

Thank you!

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? We do not want to just do your (home-)work for you; we want you to gain understanding. However, as it is we do not know what your underlying problem is, so we can not begin to help. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/594/the-return-of-the-homework-question) for a relevant discussion. If you are uncertain how to improve your question, why not ask around in [chat]? You may also want to check out our [reference questions](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/599/).

Answer (score 1):

Since $\hat\delta$ is defined as the transitive closure of $\delta$, definition 1 trivially follows from definition 2 and vice versa.